# Why $\Bbb{C}/G \cong \Bbb{C}^*/G^*$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $G = \{g \mid g: z\mapsto z +k+l\omega ,\text{ with } k,l \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ (where $\text{Im}\ \omega >0$) be group of translation  acting on $\Bbb{C}$.

Under the exponential map $\exp(2\pi i):\Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}^*$ we have another action $G^* = \{g^* \mid g^*:z\mapsto z\cdot e^{2\pi i  n\omega} , \text{with } n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ which is action on $\Bbb{C}^*$, and we can check that expoential map given above is compatible with the $G$ and $G^*$ action that is $$\exp(2\pi i)(g\cdot z) = g^*\cdot \exp(2\pi i)(z)$$

with $g(z) = z+ m_1\omega + m_2 \in G$ and $g^* = e^{2\pi i m_1 \omega} \in G^*$

---

I want to prove that quotient space are the same that is :

$$\Bbb{C}/G \cong \Bbb{C}^*/G^*$$

I know if $f:X\to Y$ is $G$ - equivariant homeomorphism then $X/G \cong Y/G$  but here the expoential map is no longer homeomorphism, how to gurantee that it's still induced homeomorphism on the quotient?

Comment: What are the equivalence classes of $\mathbb C / G$?

Comment: that is the orbit of the group action $z \sim z'$ iff exist some $g \in G$ such that $g\cdot z = z'$ @AlvinL

Comment: What is the purpose of writing $z \mapsto z+1+\omega$ instead of $z \mapsto z+\omega'$?

Comment: As you write it, this does not really make sense: $G$ is not a group, If you want to get a torus there, you should have something like the translations of the form $z\mapsto z+k+\ell \omega$ for $k,\ell\in\mathbb Z$, (This indeed is a group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$.)

Comment: Probably you want to have $\omega = i$ .

Comment: @Paul Frost  , do you mean to gain some intuition, I see the group action on $\Bbb{C}^*$ roll up the annulus? Does this means this isomorphism is specific to the torus and not a universal construction?

Comment: It's been a while since the last comment; have you shown that $\exp$ induces a holomorphic bijection?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang ,I am not sure. $\exp$ can not be a holomorphic bijection since the space on both side are topologically different?

Comment: I follow the Paul Frost's comment and found that $\Bbb{C}^* \cong S^1 \times \Bbb{R}^+$ and when $\omega = i$ it's the action on $\Bbb{R}^+$ it warps it to $S^1$ therefore isomorphic $S^1 \times S^1 \cong \Bbb{T}^1$? this construction is very similar to the Hopf surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Numbers}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\Numbers{C}}\newcommand{\Ints}{\Numbers{Z}}$As in the question, fix a complex number $\omega$ with positive imaginary part (and, if desired without loss of generality, satisfying $|\operatorname{im}\omega| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $1 \leq |\omega|$). Introduce the additive subgroup
$$
G = \Ints + \Ints\omega = \{k + \ell\omega : k,\ \ell \in \Ints\} \subset (\Cpx, +)
$$
acting by translations, and the multiplicative subgroup
$$
G^{*} = \{\exp(2\pi in\omega) : n \in \Ints\} \subset (\Cpx^{\times}, \cdot)
$$
acting by complex multiplication.

Details to fill in as needed:

- $G^{*} = \exp(G)$. Specifically, $\exp$ induces a surjection from $G = \Ints + \Ints\omega$ to $G^{*}$ with kernel $\Ints$.
- The covering map $\exp:\Cpx \to \Cpx^{\times}$ followed by the quotient map $\Cpx^{\times} \to \Cpx^{\times}/G^{*}$ factors through the quotient, inducing a bijection $\Cpx/G \to \Cpx^{\times}/G^{*}$. Because the group actions are via biholomorphisms and $\exp$ is a holomorphic covering map (hence a local biholomorphism), this bijection is a biholomorphism.
- Regarding the *without loss of generality* claim, every integer lattice in $(\Cpx, +)$ is, up to scaling and rotation, generated by $1$ and a complex number $\omega$, the *modulus*, satisfying $|\operatorname{im}\omega| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $1 \leq |\omega|$, and two such lattices are equal if and only if their moduli differ by $\pm1$ or are negative reciprocals. (Geometrically, the boundary of the [*modular domain*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481463/transformations-between-the-fundamental-domains-of-eisenstein-series) is glued up by folding along the center line.)

---

Bart de Smit and Hendrik Lenstra used these ideas in a [2004 article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200304/fea-escher.pdf) in the *AMS Notices* to [analyze the Droste effect](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/en/research/research-projects/science/escher-and-the-droste-effect) in M.C. Escher's print [*Print Gallery*](https://www.artchive.com/artchive/e/escher/escher_gallery.jpg.html). There used to be mpeg animations hosted at Leiden of infinite-zooming into the center of Escher's print based upon "unwrapping"—lifting Escher's lithograph to the universal cover—then mapping back to $\Cpx^{\times}$ after scaling and rotation. The only thing that turns up in a quick web search, however, is this youtube video https://youtu.be/9WHdyG9mJaI

Comment: thank you @Andrew D. Hwang , where do you use the without loss of generality $|\operatorname{im}\omega| \leq \frac{1}{2}
$ and $|\omega|\ge 1$? Do you have some easy to read reference book for the moduli space of the complex torus?

Comment: The _without loss of generality_ item isn't needed, it's just a related bit of mathematical culture. <> For the moduli space of the torus, I suggest just working out the details: Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be complex numbers generating a lattice $\Lambda$ (so, not real multiples of each other) and consider the extent to which these generators can be chosen without doing more than multiplying $\Lambda$ (as a set) by a non-zero constant.

Comment: got it, thank you Hwang

Comment: Wow , I have worked out all the detail of the moduli space of the torus. That's a bit long, but not very hard (Miranda discussed it in detail). but do not study the geometry of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ on the upper halfplane. @Andrew D. Hwang